# How to send SMTP emails with RabbitMQ?

Tags: java, email, rabbitmq

I'm nearly new using Message Queue, and I'm using RabbitMQ (java) How can I send SMTP messages using Rabbit? I got a git plugin from rabbitMQ https://github.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-smtp but it says "There is no support at this time for sending outgoing email from RabbitMQ" am I wrong or sending emails in RabbitMQ it's not possible?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

There is an experimental plugin which allows processing of both incoming and outgoing smtp messages:

https://github.com/gotthardp/rabbitmq-email